# Streaming Picamera from Raspberry to Public Server Webpage

Tags: html, python-3.x, sockets, video-streaming, raspberry-pi3

Currently, my Picamera attached to raspberry working with circular buffer and send livestream to my public server at the same time.

The circular buffer will keep recording and if certain event is triggered, the raspberry will send the specified length from circular buffer to the public server.

But, I also want the live stream capabilities at the same time.
So far, I have succeed to send the live stream data to my public server using socket, and then the server side python script direct the stream to vlc.exe (my public server is windows server), then play it using vlc player.
But, I want it to play in my webpage.

My problem here is, I don't know how to re-direct again the stdin data (from client using socket) vlc.exe to html webpage, which will be accessed by anyone who want to see the video live stream.

I have search several methods like :

- mpeg stream, but I'm using a stream of h264 here not multiple jpeg images.
- mplayer, which I also stuck at redirecting the stdin to html page.
- vlc command from raspberry (cvlc) which I found did not had the same command option with vlc.exe for windows. For example, I did not find --sout option in vlc-help.txt.
- Most tutorials only cover LAN network, while I have to stream it remotely.

CMIIW.

So, is there someone who knows how to direct the h264 stream from python socket to html webpage in windows server ?